# Different quadratic forms

Tags: quadratic-forms

I don't have a math background and am familiar with only the standard form of the quadratic formula, $y=ax^2 + bx + c$

What is the proper name for this formula I've just seen also referred to as a quadratic form?:

$f(w)=\frac{1}{2}w^TAw-b^Tw$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *quadratic formula* is an analytic solution to the question of finding the roots of a polynomial of degree $2$ over a field.

A *quadratic form* is a homogeneous polynomial of degree two in a number of variables.  You can also formulate this abstractly as a function $q:V\to F$ where $V$ is an $F$ vector space, and $q$ has special properties.

All of this is completely explained in the wiki pages

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form

---

Given any symmetric matrix $A$, $w\mapsto w^\top Aw$ defines a quadratic form. The $-b^\top w$ term makes it not a true quadratic form, but as I search around I find it called an **extended quadratic form** in other places.

Comment: Oops I think I meant quadratic equation rather than formula.

Comment: @Austin I don't see how that matters. "Solving a quadratic equation in one variable" is precisely the same thing as finding roots of a polynomial of degree 2.

Comment: So the second example is just a quadratic form rewritten using matrices?

Comment: @Austin An **extended** quadratic form, as I mentioned in the post.  And yes, for quadratic forms over $\mathbb R$, there is this thing you can do to translate between an expression like $x^\top Ax$ and a homogeneous polynomial of degree $2$.